# Laravel inserts two user records at register, how to prevent this?

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I am creating an application where I have to insert a user at registration with custom fields. As found online, i customised the create method in the Laravel RegisterController. However, now the application inserts two user records whenever I register a new user. Can someone help me with this please?

Here is the code of my create method in the RegisterController

```
protected function create(array $data)
    {
        /********************************************************************************
         * CALCULATE ALL THE NEEDED DATA FOR THE USER
         ********************************************************************************/

        // Delete the uncompleted registration
        UncompletedRegistration::deleteByEmail($data['email']);

        // Set the right values based on the filled values
        $compercentagecreative = 0.0;
        $compercentagenotcreative = 0.0;
        $creativepercent = 0.0;

        switch ($data['headjob']) {
            case 1:
                $compercentagecreative = config('constants.percentageRates.comPercentageCreative.headjob');
                $compercentagenotcreative = config('constants.percentageRates.comPercentageNotCreative.headjob');
                $creativepercent = config('constants.percentageRates.creativePercent.headjob');
                break;
            case 2:
                $compercentagecreative = config('constants.percentageRates.comPercentageCreative.notheadjob');
                $compercentagenotcreative = config('constants.percentageRates.comPercentageNotCreative.notheadjob');
                $creativepercent = config('constants.percentageRates.creativePercent.notheadjob');
                break;
            default:
                $compercentagecreative = config('constants.percentageRates.comPercentageCreative.headjob');
                $compercentagenotcreative = config('constants.percentageRates.comPercentageNotCreative.headjob');
                $creativepercent = config('constants.percentageRates.creativePercent.headjob');
                break;
        }

        // Format the VAT number
        $data['vatnumber'] = Helper::formatVatNumber($data['vatnumber']);

        $isVatValid = false;

        try {
            // Check if vat is valid
            $response = Helper::checkVat($data['vatnumber']);
            $responseArray = json_decode($response);

            $isVatValid = $responseArray->valid;
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            $isVatValid = false;
        }

        // Generate an activation key
        $activationKey = md5(uniqid('CS', true));


        /********************************************************************************
         * CREATE THE USER IN THE DATABASE
         ********************************************************************************/

        // Create the user and insert in the database
        return User::create([
            'usertype'                      => config('constants.userTypes.USER'),
            'registeredon'                  => strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")),
            'activationkey'                 => $activationKey,
            'language'                      => 'nl',
            'email'                         => Helper::truncate($data['email']),
            'fullname'                      => Helper::truncate($data['lastname'] . ' ' . $data['firstname']),
            'firstname'                     => Helper::truncate($data['firstname']),
            'lastname'                      => Helper::truncate($data['lastname']),
            'password'                      => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'lastloginon'                   => strtotime('now'),
            'lastloginip'                   => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
            'activatedon'                   => strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('1970-01-01 00:00:00'))),
            'deleted'                       => false,
            'companyname'                   => Helper::truncate($data['companyname']),
            'street'                        => Helper::truncate($data['street']),
            'number'                        => Helper::truncate($data['number']),
            'city'                          => Helper::truncate($data['city']),
            'zipcode'                       => Helper::truncate($data['zipcode']),
            'vatnumber'                     => Helper::truncate($data['vatnumber']),
            'validvat'                      => $isVatValid,
            'website'                       => Helper::truncate($data['website']),
            'phonenumber'                   => Helper::truncate($data['phonenumber']),
            'bankname'                      => Helper::truncate($data['bank']),
            'iban'                          => Helper::truncate($data['iban']),
            'bicswift'                      => Helper::truncate($data['bicswift']),
            'paymentremindermode'           => $data['paymentremindermode'],
            'invoicecreationremindermode'   => 2,
            'nettosavedmailmode'            => 1,
            'zombiemailsent'                => 0,
            'zombiemail180sent'             => 0,
            'nettosavedperinvoicmailemode'  => 1,
            'logo'                          => NULL,
            'emailaccepted'                 => false,
            'contractaccepted'              => false,
            'compercentagecreative'         => $compercentagecreative,
            'compercentagenotcreative'      => $compercentagenotcreative,
            'contractdate'                  => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
            'creativepercent'               => $creativepercent,
            'activity'                      => $data['activity'],
            'headjob'                       => $data['headjob'],
            'template'                      => config('constants.templates.ORIGINAL'),
            'freebtw'                       => isset($data['freebtw']) ? ($data['freebtw'] == "on" ? true : false) : false,
            'refid'                         => Input::get('invite_id'),
            'api_key'                       => Helper::generateRandomString(40),
            'allowed_quotation'             => true,
            'send_bcc'                      => false
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: What would cause this method to be called twice? Can you show the RegisterController action that calls the create method? Does this happen everytime or if the user double submits the form?

Comment: I don't know where this is called because this is an override function (I think). It is automatically called by the Laravel Authentication System

Comment: Did you change the form for Registration? Can you include part of that view? Most likely the form is being submitted twice.